# how to repair data so foreign keys can be added back to database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have just discovered my database which has been moved between a few servers in the last few months was, in one of the database dumps, converted to myisam and all the foreign key constraints nuked (not impressed). I've converted all the tables back to innodb with a php script but now I'm finding half the constraints are failing to add.

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`identicar2`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-2a7_c0'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-2a7_c0_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`feature_sk`) REFERENCES `tbl_feature_list` (`feature_sk`))
```

I'm lost now, I can't go through thousands of records manually. what is the best thing to do in order to get my database back into shape?

I can provide table structures if you want but I imagine any solution will be independant of the exact structure anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution: (containing the obvious danger of losing data you may want to keep)

```
UPDATE table
SET fkColumn = NULL
WHERE fkColumn NOT IN (SELECT referenceColumn FROM referencedTable)
```

If you just want to find them:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE fkColumn NOT IN (SELECT referenceColumn FROM referencedTable)
```

Comment: If the fkColumn's value doesn't reference any existing parent row, then it's invalid data anyway so nulling it shouldn't matter. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin In the database's current state, this data may not mean much, but you may have at some point deleted the referenced record and may want to go about restoring an older version of the DB to find this data (at least theoretically).

Comment: Yep I know my comment is theoretical only.  In real life, we'd want to identify all the unmatched fk values as in your SELECT example, and then decide on a case-by-case basis what to do with them.

Comment: Worked well, I ended up using `DELETE FROM table WHERE...` to do the actual cleaning. Thanks for an elegant solution :)